# How many servers in a microservice architecture?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

I just want to check my understanding of a microservice architecture.

I have 5 different apps that I'm building and running in their own Dockerfile.
Each docker file first builds that app before pulling the Apache httpd image and moving the built files over to its server.

This means that all 5 apps have separate httpd servers serving that application at different urls. Each app communicates with the other, getting the necessary resources over http.

I'm looking to deploy this in Kubernetes.

Is it normal to have a server per service? *or* would you create a separate server container and copy all the files over to that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is normal, each microservice should have  its own web server, so that they run in isolation and can be scaled individually.

Comment: Yeah, i thought so, thanks a lot. Do you have any resources to hand that specifically mentions the use of servers? I couldn't find any online

Comment: A great place to start is the book `Building Microservices - Designing Fine-Grained Systems` by Sam Newman (ISBN 9781492034025). There are many more reason why we want to keep our microservices separated from each and the book covers them well, this actually starts already at page 3 in chapter 1 with the heading: `Microservices -> What Are Microservices -> Autonomous`.